# Wordpress, add post to custom taxonomy's category

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a post to a category under taxonomy cate. The code I am using is:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['user'] );
$id = array(
    'post_title'    => $_POST['title'],
    'post_content'  => $_POST['content'],
    'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author'   => $user->ID,
    'taxonomy' => ('cate'),
    'post_type'     => 'ad',
    'post_category' => array(425),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
); 
 $user_id = wp_insert_post($id);
if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
   $odgovor["success"] = 1;

}
```

The post is added but it's added under category 'uncategorized" and not under desired category ID. This system works properly when custom post type is not used. (In this case taxonomy 'cate')

Any ideas?

Comment: You should ask this question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
$id = array(
        'post_title'    => $_POST['title'],
        'post_content'  => $_POST['content'],
        'post_date'     => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'post_author'   => $user->ID,
        'post_type'     => 'ad',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    ); 
     $user_id = wp_insert_post($id);
     wp_set_object_terms($user_id, 416, 'cate', true);
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user_id ) ) {
       $odgovor["success"] = 1;

    }
```

Josh showed me the way, but his syntax wasn't right. It' category first, taxonomy second, and some things had to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need [wp_set_object_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms), which takes post ID, terms, taxonomy, and append as parameters. For example:

```
$user_id = wp_insert_post( $id );

wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, 'cate', 'category', true );
```

Comment: Can this be done directly on wp_insert_post without calling the second function?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: Is category as a term or do I enter category ID instead of 'category'? Can you please edit my code above? I added "wp_set_object_terms( $user_id, 'cate', 'category', true );" and it's uncategorised again...